# when use espresso and android studio debug, 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut''. Check device logcat for details

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

it raise:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'keyDispatchingTimedOut'
```

the full log after debug session interruption is [here](https://gist.github.com/60c8fde1a363527155aba540dfae3cb3)

Comment: hi. Any progress on this?